# Problemas javascript html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, dom

Estoy tratando de llamar un input dentro del árbol DOM pero no puedo llamarlo por la clase "active", sin embargo cuando uso `task-wrapper` el `alert` me aparece perfectamente.

¿Cómo lo soluciono?

```js
    $(".active > .hideinfo > .wrapper-calendar > .since > .date > .dateBegin").on("click", function(){
        alert("hola");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="task-wrapper ribbon ribbon-bookmark ribbon-danger active" data-taskid="1" style="background-size: 20% 40px;">
    <span class="newball"><span class="magictimeslow newballpulse"></span></span>
    <label class="titlecheck css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
        <input type="checkbox"><span></span>
    </label>
    <span class="name">prueba 1</span>
    <span class="attach"></span>
    <span class="eta"> 
        Faltan 9 días 
    </span>
    <div class="notice-wrapper">
        <i class="si si-bell"></i> 
        36 día(s) antes
    </div>
    <div class="ribbon-box"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></i></div>
        <div class="tags">
    <span class="tag">pruebas</span><span class="tag">tested</span><span class="tag">otra tag</span>
    <div class="newitemfloating"><i class="creartag si si-plus"></i></div><input type="text" class="inputTag" name="inputTag" data-taskid="1" data-employee="6">
    </div>
    <div class="icons-wrapper">
        <i class="si si-calendar magictimefast swashIn" data-type="calendar" data-anitime="100" style="display: inline-block;"></i>
        <i class="si si-users magictimefast swashIn active" data-type="asigned" data-anitime="100" style="display: inline-block;"><div class="task-nots">1</div></i>
        <i class="si si-layers magictimefast swashIn" data-type="subtasks" data-anitime="100" style="display: inline-block;"><div class="task-nots">3</div></i>
        <i class="si si-paper-clip magictimefast swashIn" data-type="attachment" data-anitime="100" style="display: inline-block;"><div class="task-nots">3</div></i>
        <i class="si si-bubble magictimefast swashIn" data-type="conversation" data-anitime="100" style="display: inline-block;"><div class="task-nots">1</div></i>
    </div>
    <div class="hideinfo">
        <div class="wrapper-calendar" data-type="calendar" style="display: none;">
            <span class="title">Fechas</span>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="date-wrapper since">
                <span class="author">Desde: </span>
                <div class="js-datetimepicker input-group date" data-side-by-side="true">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="si si-calendar magictimefast swashIn" style="display: inline-block;"></i>
                    </span>
                    <input class="form-control dateBegin" type="text" id="" placeholder="2017-04-18 00:00:00 ">     
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="date-wrapper until">
                <span class="author">Hasta:</span>
                <div class="js-datetimepicker input-group date" data-side-by-side="true">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="si si-calendar magictimefast swashIn" style="display: inline-block;"></i>
                    </span>
                    <input class="form-control dateEnd" type="text" id="" placeholder="2017-04-19 00:00:00">                                                       
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A mi me funciona bien el `onclick` tal y como lo tienes (quitando el `display:none`). Y no te es mas facil poniendo el `onclick` usando el `ID` del elemento?

Comment: Algo debo tener mal, porque a mi no me funciona en el programa completo. 
Si seria mas sencillo pero estoy generando los elementos dinámicamente con PHP por lo que no puedo usar Id's sino la clase "active" que se añade al desplegar el elemento.

Comment: Pues no se qué puede ser ya que el ejemplo que provees si funciona :/  Igualmente no hace falta toda la cadena de clases. con `$(".dateBegin").on("click", function(){` basta

Comment: ya tengo solución aunque aún no se el motivo, en cuanto tenga un poco de tiempo escribo la respuesta para que opinéis y le sirva de ayuda a alguien que le ocurra lo mismo

Comment: Perfecto, cuando la escribas, avisame por estos comentarios, me interesa ver qué pasó ^^

Comment: Al final se ha cerrado la pregunta y todo sin poder responder, pero explico por aquí donde estaba el fallo.

Al intentar llamar a la clase ".active" la cual se añade dinámicamente no funciona el alert, para solucionarlo tuve que llamar al .hiddeninfo y una vez dentro ya si puedo llamar a la clase ".active" para cambiar solo los hijos pertenecientes al padre clase active

Answer (score 0):

Porque no pruebas con el selector `:visible`

```js
$("input:visible").on("click", function(){
        alert("hola");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="task-wrapper ribbon ribbon-bookmark ribbon-danger active" data-taskid="1" style="background-size: 20% 40px;">
    <span class="newball"><span class="magictimeslow newballpulse"></span></span>
    <label class="titlecheck css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
        <input type="checkbox"><span></span>
    </label>
    <span class="name">prueba 1</span>
    <span class="attach"></span>
    <span class="eta"> 
        Faltan 9 días 
    </span>
    <div class="notice-wrapper">
        <i class="si si-bell"></i> 
        36 día(s) antes
    </div>
    <div class="ribbon-box"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></i></div>
        <div class="tags">
    <span class="tag">pruebas</span><span class="tag">tested</span><span class="tag">otra tag</span>
    <div class="newitemfloating"><i class="creartag si si-plus"></i></div><input type="text" class="inputTag" name="inputTag" data-taskid="1" data-employee="6">
    </div>
    <div class="icons-wrapper">
        <i class="si si-calendar magictimefast swashIn" data-type="calendar" data-anitime="100" style="display: inline-block;"></i>
        <i class="si si-users magictimefast swashIn active" data-type="asigned" data-anitime="100" style="display: inline-block;"><div class="task-nots">1</div></i>
        <i class="si si-layers magictimefast swashIn" data-type="subtasks" data-anitime="100" style="display: inline-block;"><div class="task-nots">3</div></i>
        <i class="si si-paper-clip magictimefast swashIn" data-type="attachment" data-anitime="100" style="display: inline-block;"><div class="task-nots">3</div></i>
        <i class="si si-bubble magictimefast swashIn" data-type="conversation" data-anitime="100" style="display: inline-block;"><div class="task-nots">1</div></i>
    </div>
    <div class="hideinfo">
        <div class="wrapper-calendar" data-type="calendar" style="display: none;">
            <span class="title">Fechas</span>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="date-wrapper since">
                <span class="author">Desde: </span>
                <div class="js-datetimepicker input-group date" data-side-by-side="true">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="si si-calendar magictimefast swashIn" style="display: inline-block;"></i>
                    </span>
                    <input class="form-control dateBegin" type="text" id="" placeholder="2017-04-18 00:00:00 ">     
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="date-wrapper until">
                <span class="author">Hasta:</span>
                <div class="js-datetimepicker input-group date" data-side-by-side="true">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="si si-calendar magictimefast swashIn" style="display: inline-block;"></i>
                    </span>
                    <input class="form-control dateEnd" type="text" id="" placeholder="2017-04-19 00:00:00">                                                       
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```